# how to write a regular expression for matching a string with '.' (fullstop) in between and ends with a comma?

Tags: java, regex

```
string input= "devname=B399601569,devid=B39601569,logid=000013,type=traffic,srcip=192.168.192.123,srcport=2072,dstip=10.180.1.105,dstport=3206"
```

This is the expression I tried:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(srcip=)(\\d+)((.*)?)(dstip=)(\\d+)(\\.)*");
```

it prints only: srcip=192 dstip=10

but i was looking for srcip=192.168.192.123 dstip=10.180.1.105 
any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grouping parentheses are wrong; you want

```
(\\d+\\.)+\\d+
```

not

```
(\\d+)(\\.)*
```

The latter would allow for any number of periods (zero or more, greedy) but not allow anything more after the last period.

In some more detail,

```
(srcip=(?:(?:\\d+\\.)+\\d+)(?:.*)?(dstip=(?:\\d+\\.)+\\d+)
```

would capture the `srcip=` with its IP address into the first group, and `dstip=` and its IP address into the second.  The `(?:...)` construct allows for parentheses which do not create a new matching group.

Of course, you could add grouping parentheses to extract just the IP addresses if you want.  Groups are counted from the left, each opening parenthesis which is not `(?:` creates another group.

Comment: thank you sir, i got a partial output :   Srcip: dstip=10.180.1.105 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 2                                                                                                                                       ___I have written the output statements as:                                                                  System.out.print("Srcip: " + m.group(1) + " " );
 System.out.println("Dstip: " + m.group(2));                                                         ____I guess this must be my mistake. any suggestions on this?

Comment: Looks like perhaps you misplaced one of the parentheses?